# ubuntu 14.10 and postgres 9.4 how to run pg_controldata

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, archiving

I have a server with `pg_xlog` directory filled up. I need to determine the WAL(Write Ahead Log) files to delete and according to [this link](http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/09/pgxlog-disk-space-problem-on-postgres.html) i need `pg_controldata` which is not available in ubuntu with postgresql-contrib-9.4 installed.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. We are not general software/server tech support. Try the DBA SE site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `locate pg_controldata` to locate it at `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/pg_controldata`.

Alternatively, use `find / -name pg_controldata`. Ideally you would search somewhere more specific than the filesystem root.